# Setting the value and style (color) of a cell in pandas Dataframe at the same time in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've written a python program to look for and fix syntax errors in an excel spreadsheet.  This part works.

If a cell has a correctable syntax error, the value in the cell should be fixed and the cell highlighted in yellow.

If the syntax error is not correctable (there is not enough information available to correct it), the value of the cell should be left unchanged, but the cell should be highlighted in red.  This is the part I can't seem to get to work.

I can update the value of the cell or highlight it, but all my attempts to do both fails.

I've used commands like

```
df.at[row,col] = value
```

to update an individual cell, and this works. And

```
def colorCell(df):
    color = 'background-color: red; font-weight: bold'

    dfTemp = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

    for i in df[df["UserId"].str.match(userIdPat) != True]["UserId"].index:
        dfTemp.at[i,"UserId"] = color

    for i in df[df["Phone Number"].str.match(phonePat) != True]["Phone Number"].index:
        dfTemp.at[i,"Phone Number"] = color

    for i in df[df["MAC Address"].str.match(macPat) != True]["MAC Address"].index:
        dfTemp.at[i,"MAC Address"] = color

    return dfTemp

df2 = df.style.apply(colorCell, axis=None)
```

to color the cells, but I can't seem to get both setting a value and setting the style to work at the same time.

Part of the problem is that I'm modifying the value in place (df), while I'm creating a new dataframe to set the color (df2).  If I write df2 back into df, I get errors that "**AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'at'**" the next time I try to set another cell value using

```
df.at[row,col] = value
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this, but I am just not seeing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a short example program with a very simple input that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1):

@user545424 Thanks for suggesting I post a short example.  In doing so I solved my own issue.

My original issue was that I had to separate dataframes, one for the data, and a separate one for the style. In coming up with a short example I found a way to do everything with one dataframe (I'm very new to both python and pandas).

The fix I came up with is to create the original dataframe including ".style".

So in place of this command (which I was using):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I now create df using this command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).style
```

Now, when I want to access/change the data part of df, I reference it as "df.data", and when I want to apply the style part of df, I reference it as "df.apply".  This way I can access both the data and the style with one dataframe.  Here is the example code I was writing when I discovered my answer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def colorCell(df, row=None, column=None, color="red"):
    color = f"background-color: {color}; font-weight: bold"
    dfTemp = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    dfTemp.at[row,column] = color
    return dfTemp

# Create the dataframe including styles.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).style

# Update location [1,"A"] and set it to "red".
df.data.loc[1,"A"] = 999
df.apply(colorCell, row=1, column="A", color="red", axis=None)

# Update location [2,"B"] and set it to "yellow".
df.data.loc[2,"B"] = 999
df.apply(colorCell, row=2, column="B", color="yellow", axis=None)
```

As I said above, I'm very new to python, and even newer to pandas.  So just because the above works, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!